# Existe ganho de desempenho usando .replace() em vez de .put() em uma Map?

Tags: java, desempenho, hashmap

Existe algum ganho de desempenho usando o método `.replace()` em vez de usar `.put()` em uma `Map`.

Estudando `Maps` notei que o método `.put()` e `.replace()` possuem praticamente a mesma função. Fiz um código simples e testei e o resultando foi o mesmo em ambos os casos:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Lista = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void methodTeste(String teste, String outra) {
    if (Lista.containsKey(teste)) {
        Lista.replace(teste, outra);
    } else {
        Lista.put(teste, outro);
    }
}

public void methodTeste(String teste, String outra) {
    Lista.put(teste, outro);
}
```

Qual dos dois códigos irá obter melhor desempenho?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após vários testes cheguei a uma conclusão:
O `.replace` só deve ser usado quando você tem certeza que a KEY já existe.
Se você não tem certeza da existencia da KEY (igual o meu caso) é mais vantajoso a utilização do .put direito.

No teste onde a existência da `KEY` era certa e não havia necessidade de verificações o `.replace` ganhou facilmente:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Lista = new HashMap<>();

private static void methodTeste1(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Lista.replace(teste, outra);    
    }
}

private static void methodTeste2(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Lista.put(teste, outra);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long inicio, fim;
    Lista.put("antonio", "antonio");

    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste1("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Replace: " + (fim-inicio)  + " ms");

    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste2("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Put: " + (fim-inicio) + " ms");
}
```

No teste onde a existência da KEY não era certa e nós eramos obrigados a fazer verificações o `.put` obteve um desempenho significativamente maior:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Lista = new HashMap<>();

private static void methodTeste1(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (Lista.containsKey("antonio")) {
            Lista.replace(teste, outra);
        } else {
            Lista.put(teste, outra);
        }
    }
}

private static void methodTeste2(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Lista.put(teste, outra);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long inicio, fim;

    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste1("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Replace: " + (fim-inicio)  + " ms");

    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste2("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Put: " + (fim-inicio) + " ms");
}
```

Conclusão: `.replace` possui desempenho maior que `.put` mas tudo vai depender da situação.

Comment: Não, é o oposto disto.

Comment: ??????? não entendi

Comment: leia minha resposta de novo, agora com atenção. Eu negritei coisas importantes. A questão toda já está errada, por isso a conclusão só pode ser errada. A comparação está sendo feita entre laranjas e bananas. Na minha resposta eu coloco a equivalência de códigos. Quando você testa códigos que produzem resultados diferentes não dá para olhar o desempenho. O primeiro código testa coisas diferentes, mas do jeito certo, o segundo testa coisas diferentes e do jeito errado.

Answer (score 4):

`replace()` é mais eficiente nos casos onde não exista um chave que está sendo usada nele. Ele só pode substituir um valor de uma chave existente, executa nada se não tiver a chave. Já o `put()` colocará um valor ali, se existir a chave será igual ao `replace()`, mas se não existir terá que criar a chave no mapa, o que tem custo extra.

Mas **a performance não deveria ser considerada, o importante é a semântica** que quer dar, eles dão resultados diferentes em certas circunstâncias, conforme mostrado acima, então uso o que precisa.

Neste seu exemplo o teste não faz sentido (obviamente que **o primeiro será mais lento, ele faz muito mais e dá resultado diferente do segundo, não faz sentido comparar essas duas coisa**). Se o que deseja é só mudar o valor se a chave existir e não criar um novo, use o `replace()`. Para obter o mesmo resultado com `put()` teria que fazer assim:

```
if (Lista.containsKey(teste)) lista.put(teste, outro);
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
lista.replace(teste, outra);
```

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#replace-K-V-).

O teste adequado seria assim:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static HashMap<String, String> lista = new HashMap<>();
    
    private static void Put(String teste, String outra) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) if (lista.containsKey("antonio")) lista.put(teste, outra);
    }
    
    private static void Replace(String teste, String outra) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) lista.replace(teste, outra);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Put("antonio", "antonio");
        System.out.println("Put: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - inicio)  + " ms");
        inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Replace("antonio", "antonio");
        System.out.println("Replace: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - inicio) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/d35WpV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/prkkcfkb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/MapPerformance.java).

Comment: Eu acho que o .replace só deve ser usado em casos onde o usuario tem certeza que a KEY existe... no meu caso onde eu não sei se a KEY já existe é muito melhor usar .put direto... Fazendo os testes propostos pelo Antonio Santos isso foi muito perceptível o desempenho ganho usando .put direto em vez de fazer as verificações. Mas valeu pelo aprendizado!

Comment: Não, depende do que a pessoa quer, não depende se ela tem certeza, ela pode querer que faça nada quando a chave não existe, portanto o `replace()` é o posto do que está dizendo, o `put()` até seria o caso de saber usado se ele tem certeza da existência se ela não quer que crie uma chave nova. Acho que você não leu minha resposta. Os testes não fazem sentido, está comparando coisas completamente diferentes que não se relacionam. Se você não entender isso não houve aprendizado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar put() com uma chave que existe, será sobrescrita.
O map não matém chave duplicadas.
Você usa o replace para sobrescrever e o put para adicionar, porém o put faz os dois.

Comment: Sim isso eu aprendi, mas queria saber em relação ao desempenho oque isso muda... como sugestão irei fazer os testes abaixo!

Comment: Existe algum motivo para dar 2 respostas?

Answer (score 0):

Faça esse teste simples:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Lista = new HashMap<>();

private static void methodTeste1(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (Lista.size() > 0) {
            Lista.replace(teste, outra);
        } else {
            Lista.put(teste, outra);
        }
    }
}

private static void methodTeste2(String teste, String outra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Lista.put(teste, outra);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long inicio, fim;

    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste1("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Replace: " + (fim-inicio)  + " ms");


    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    methodTeste2("antonio", "antonio");
    fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Put: " + (fim-inicio) + " ms");
}
```

Comment: Dá uma lida na minha resposta.

Comment: Respondemos juntos.

Comment: É que a sua resposta testa coisa complemente diferente, não importa qual é mais rápido, eles não dão o mesmo resultado.

Comment: O que eu fiz é ajudar no teste dele. A penas isso. Apenas para ele tirar suas conclusões com base no que ele quer testar. Tudo é válido.

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações eu coloquei pra verificar se Lista.contains("antonio") e também fiz outros testes e como já era de se esperar o .replace foi mais lento que o .put em todos os 10 testes... é claro que a variações em alguns casos ele demorou 1ms a mais em outros ele demorou 10ms a mais... mas em larga escala isso pode acabar virando SEGUNDOS... creio eu que não há necessidade de usar uma verificação e usar replace no meu caso, vale mais a pena usar .put direto.

Comment: Eu so uso o put() em todos esses casos.